# Beginner : Springs with Hibernate 4 doubts

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My Hibernate.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My controller

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    Category category = new Category();
    category.setName("Hello");
    categoryDao.saveCategory(category);
    return "index";
}
```

My DAO

```
@Transactional
public void saveCategory(Category category) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(category);
    Category category2 = (Category) session.get(Category.class,
            new Integer(0));

    System.out.println("xxxx" + category2.getName());
}
```

I skipped my BO currently for testing purpose. Otherwise am I going somewhere? My output should have been xxxxParent which is the name of category at id = 0 however its showing xxxxHello which is being passed from Controller. Otherwise insertion is working properly. Also is there any mistake in the way am trying to access DB via Hibernate. I mean using transactional annotation or opening session.

**EDIT**

When I deleted the codes for saving new category the correct output is shown. On checking the console previously only insert was working but now select is also working.

Comment: Check this link which has very good explanation and Spring and Hibernate integrations http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/integrating-spring-framework-with-hibernate-orm-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the code

```
Category category = new Category();
category.setName("Hello");`
```

is creating an entity with id 0 (integer defaults to 0 if not declared) and is updating the existing entity in the DB. I don't see you explicitly setting the ID here. Please set the id and see.